# Structure from Motion or SLAM for windows?

Tags: windows, opencv3.0, slam-algorithm, structure-from-motion

Is there any libraries that can be used on windows for using SfM or SLAM?
This will be in python btw

So far everything I am seeing is in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about Sfm I assume you are looking for visual SLAM solutions. These solutions are computationally expensive, because you basically deal with a lot of iterative minimizations on large parameter spaces. Because of that, high-level languages are poorly suited for that task. So, I can recomment one of two things (depending on the precision you need):

1) Don't use SFM or SLAM, but just some simple visual odometry python package (quite a few on github). If you are not familiar with the term, we can say it's juste local pose computation but without the optimizations that are used in SLAM or SFM. So you might get locally decent results, but forget about globally coherent trajectories.

2) Use one of the freely available state of the art libraries such as [ORBSLAM_2_windows](https://github.com/Beewe/ORB_SLAM2_Windows) and use your own python wrappers.